# django admin hook run code from super

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, inheritance, django-admin

I want to run some code after a user has saved changes to a model in the admin. To hook into this, I know to extend the `save_model` function. How can I get it to execute all the code in `super` and then run my code?

```
class ModelNameAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('demo_field_1', 'demo_field_2')

    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        # I want to run all the code from super here
        # My code will follow...
```

When I override the `save_model` function, it only executes my code, nothing form `super`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing complicated about calling `super()` for the `ModelAdmin`, class, it's the same as you usually do in Python.

```
class ModelNameAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        super(ModelnameAdmin, self).save_model(request, obj, form, change)
        # Your code will follow ...
```

However, the only thing the [`ModelAdmin.save_model`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/4217f1cdeb070707e54fec8221b9e63e3957ef38/django/contrib/admin/options.py#L1074) method does is save the object, so you might prefer to do:

```
class ModelNameAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        obj.save()
        # Your code will follow ...
```

That's the approach used in the example in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.save_model) for `save_model`.